# What is the "correct" way to use MailKit?

Tags: c#, mailkit

I'm playing around with MailKit, and I'm wondering what will be the right approach to use?

I want my app to sync will all emails in inbox on startup, and once done, the listen for incoming emails, while I'm able to move other emails around from inbox to another subfolder.

I see that the ImapClient needs to be in "IDLE" mode to listen for incoming emails, while you have to get out of IDLE mode when you want to move emails around between folders.

Would it make sense to create 2 client connections to the same mail account? One to go into IDLE mode and listen for new incoming mails, and one to do operations on the mails in the account???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that, or you could just stop idling when new mail arrives, move whatever messages you need to move, and then re-enter IDLE mode.

Comment: The reason why I think of using two client connection is, that I don't want to loose the notifications of new mail arrived during the non-idle movement process. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Oh, well, if that's the case, you won't lose any notifications during the non-IDLE movement process. All the IDLE command does is allow the IMAP server to send notifications that it would normally send as part of responses to other commands without the client needing to send any commands.

Comment: So, to get it right, does that mean that I enter IDLE mode when there is no operations to do, and then exit idle when operations needs to be processed, and go into idle again when no operations? I guess I need to implement a timer also, to handle keep-alive of the connection?

Comment: Correct, correct, and correct. Check out the ImapIdle sample in the MailKit git repo to see any example of using timers with IDLE.